# How can I change the position of my navbar to fixed after scrolling to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change my navbar position to fixed.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var topDist = $("#container").position();
    if (scroll > topDist.top) {
      $('nav').css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "top": "0"
      });
    } else {
      $('nav').css({
        "position": "static",
        "top": "auto"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">LINK 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LINK 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LINK 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LINK 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

This is the [demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/TheIrfan/zLn2ob7h/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the `position: sticky` property which is well supported now on most browsers:

```
#container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wqp9430L/

#### Edit: I want to shed some light on why your JS and overall solution doesn't work.

Your JS isn't actually triggering because you're detecting `scroll` on the `$(document)` but your document and window isn't actually scrolling because your content is actually scrolling within `.parallax`. So instead of detecting the scroll on document you have to detect scroll on `parallax`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parallax').scroll(function () {
      var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
      var topDist = $("#container").offset();

      if (scroll > topDist.top) {
          $('nav').css({"position":"fixed","top":"0"});
      } else {
          $('nav').css({"position":"static","top":"auto"});
      }
  });
});
```

Now while this works in terms of getting actually scroll values: https://jsfiddle.net/wqp9430L/2/ you'll notice there's a few issues.

1. As you scroll the offset changes, so you should move `topDist` outside of the `scroll` function to get the initial value, but
2. If the fiddle loads too quickly (before you images finishes rendering) `topDist` becomes in accurate, so you'll have to ensure `topDist` is calculated after the images are fully rendered, then there's also
3. Changing your `nav` to `position: fixed` makes your nav `fixed` to the body but since you're not scrolling in the body but rather in `.parallax` you won't see the nav.

For these reason you should use the CSS solution, but if you insist on using JS you solution should look more like:

```
if (imgLoaded) {
  var topDist = $("#container").offset().top;

  $('.parallax').scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > topDist) {
      $('nav').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: scroll + 'px'
      });
    } else {
      $('nav').css({
        position: 'static',
        top: 'auto'
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadIrfanJauhari awesome, can you mark the answer?